# Windows 8 install shows NTFS partition but asks for driver

Tags: windows-8-preview

I have an Asus Eee PC 900HA, and I tried to install Windows 8 on it, so I created a 56GB NTFS partition and booted install from USB

When I get to install it, says "some drivers are missing", but when I click Explore button, I can see the NTFS partition.

I have updated the BIOS to its lastest version in Asus Support, loaded setup defaults, downloaded *all* the drivers I saw there and put them into the USB, but keeps asking for drivers.

The BIOS has no option for the HDD to be IDE or AHCI, only Auto, ARMD and CDROM are available.

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic for StackOverflow. Voting to migrate to [a more appropriate site](http://SuperUser.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is not a HDD driver it is looking for my something for the motherboard/graphics/communications/etc. Not all hardware will support a pre-release version of Windows 8.

Comment: Is there any kind of way I can know which driver is missing?

Comment: Not sure. Here is a [blog post](http://liliputing.com/2012/02/windows-8-consumer-preview-runs-well-on-netbooks-mostly.html) where the author installed Windows 8 on his Eee PC. You could ask there.

Comment: Lucky him, he's got a 1000HE, which has a bunch of Windows 7 driver downloads, but mine has not :(